Electron "clouds" in an atom
I have a very naïve understanding of atomic structure and quantum mechanics. But from what I have heard about the double slit experiment with an electron, we can say that if we shoot photons on the electron to detect its path, the pattern goes away as if the electron starts behaving like a particle.
But also every textbook writes that the electrons around the nucleus are not localised but present in the form of clouds (probability clouds).
But isn't the electron constantly interacting with the nucleus (i.e. exchanging photons)? So why wouldn't it behave like a particle and be localised all the time?

An electron is a particle also with wave properties, it always has wave properties. The pattern dissappears because an interaction has occurred after the slits. Most of your textbook was written in the 1930s/40s especially the section on light.

When the EM field exerts a force physicists use the term "virtual photons", it means we have no clue or deeper model on how the EM field exerts force, we are just using a particle exchange theory because that is the easiest or most convenient. When the EM field transfers energy we use the real photon.

Photons and electrons are small amounts of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge that gets exchanged between systems. The "particle" ontology is, unfortunately, a misnomer. Particles or corpuscles, as these terms are usually understood, don't exist in nature.

These photons are virtual photons which means Fourier components of in the simplest case the coulomb potential.

Interaction in the sense of coupling in the Hamiltonian is not a quantum measurement; if it was no system would ever stay in superposition. Measurements would become continous, which would lead to a constant Zeno effect and an altogether different physics.

I like this question, because it combines 3 intro-level quantum analogies that are fine for chemists, but are insufficient for physicists.
Let's start with the orbital: it is not a probability cloud. This gives the impression of a point electron bee-bopping around the atom, and if you were to look where it is, you would just find it where it is, with a probability distribution.
That is problematic. 1) because you can't look where it is. It's a measurement that can't be done. It's a thought experiment. 2) because a probability cloud is classical, and hence: wrong.
The electron is described by a wave function which is the complex square root of a probability cloud--whatever that means. I recommend using it as a tool to do calculations, and then maybe think about what it means later.
(On a side note, it also gives the impression that the nucleus is a rock solid point, with the electron doing all the quantum stuff--no, we solve the hydrogen atom in reduced mass coordinates: the proton is also in a matching wave function)
Then we have the part about the electron exchanging virtual photons with the nucleus. That is a quantum field theory thing, so hold on.
The probability cloud also gives the impression that the electron is moving. An important part of eigenstates of the Schrödinger equation is that they are stationary states: they never change, other than an arbitrary unobservable global phase factor that rotates at $E/\hbar$. Now there is a probability current (that is not velocity), that rotates around the nucleus in $L\ne 0$ states, but it is also stationary.
Now the virtual photons: the quantum mechanical solution to atomic orbitals is an approximation in a static background electric field. When you "turn the field on", e.g., make it a dynamical variable, several things happen:
The eigenstates are no longer exact. There is an interaction hamiltonian that links states, and hence they can transition. They are no longer stationary states, and the energy is no longer exact. This is good: it allows atoms to change.
So now we no longer have an exact analytical description of an atom, since the system includes the EM field out to infinity. It's too much.
Nevertheless, you can still break it into approximate pieces and do calculations. This involves perturbation theory, and that is described in powers of $\alpha$ (maybe squared), and these terms can be written with diagrams of virtual particles. This does not make virtual particles real. They are just pieces of an approximation to a quantum field linking states.
They are useful, when used properly, and cause all kinds of confusion when taken seriously, esp. in a non-relativistic fashion where they "borrow energy" from the vacuum (in relativistic QFT, they don't do that).
Finally: the double slit (YDSE). The amplitude to go from initial ($i$) to final state ($f$) is the sum (or path integral) of all possible paths linking $i\rightarrow f$, and in the 2 path approximation to the YDSE, you add the amplitudes for both paths and get interference.
If you observed the electron going through one slit, then that is the path it takes, so you can't add any other amplitudes. It doesn't matter how you measure it: photon, entangled partner, whatever. If you know it, there is no 2-slit interference pattern.
Now when it goes through one slit, you still don't know where it went through the slit, which has a finite width. In that case, you have to integrate over all positions in the slit, et voila: that gives you the Fourier transform of the slit, and that is a diffraction pattern.
So the takeaway is: don't take classical description of QM too literally, don't take virtual particles too literally, and know what approximations you're description of a system is making (and you have to make them, or the problem cannot be solved).

An electron is simply a small amount of energy, momentum, angular momentum and charge (electric and leptonic). These physical properties can only be detected with an irreversible energy exchange process that transfers the energy from the quantum system to an external "measurement" system (or, in case of QFT, scatters this energy towards infinity). We know exactly what "whatever that means" means, but one has to let go of any kind of physical representations for quanta. Quanta are really just physical properties that are locally conserved or almost conserved.

As an amateur, this answer helped me a lot. One thing I didn't get is: "Now there is a probability current (that is not velocity), that rotates around the nucleus in ≠0 states, but it is also stationary." Is the emphasized contradiction intentional, or does "stationary" in this case mean "not moving by translation" (e.g. rotation does not contradict being stationary in these senses), or is it a typo, or a simplification, or other?

@ToddWilcox Probabilities are mathematical abstracts that we use to describe other abstracts called "an ensemble". They are not actual physical observables. That is already so in classical physics. Stationary in this case means in the sense of "The probability distribution of fair dice is constant.". You also have to understand that the SE for hydrogen is a toy model at this level. It can, for instance, not predict the transition of excited electronic states into the ground state and it even violates momentum conservation.

@FlatterMann I don’t understand your comment (for example, for me “SE” = “Stack Exchange”), and as far as I can tell, your comment doesn’t even attempt to answer the question of how something can both rotate and be stationary.

@ToddWilcox Apologies. SE = Schroedinger equation. Technically everything in quantum mechanics is a high dimensional rotation because of the unitarity of the ensemble theory (unitarity just means that all the ensemble members at the beginning of a quantum experiment are still there at the end and mathematically the length of the wave function vector doesn't change = rotation). That excited states are stationary in time is just an artifact of the non-relativistic toy model. All excited states have to decay, we just can't model that well with a SE. For that we need quantum field theory like QED.

@ToddWilcox I was just reading it and was thing about wt- does "stationary" mean, and I think it's a math thing: it just remains the same. Looking at the formula for current, it resolves to the expectation value of the momentum divided by mass (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current), so it kinda is a velocity, but like position, it's distributed everywhere. My understanding of the atom increased when I got a PhD in quark-structure-of-nucleons: the force is so strong, none of these approximation work, and you're dealing with a quantum blob. Wavefunctions aren't even used.

Short answer: Because the electron is entangled with the nucleus.
Longer answer:  For simplicity, consider the decay of a pion particle. The pion has spin zero. If you don't know what spin is, don't worry. The important thing is that each particle can carry a certain number we call spin and that the total spin is always conserved. The pion decays into two particles (call them particle A and particle B), each of which have a spin with magnitude $1/2$. Since the pion has a spin of zero and spin is conserved, the spins of the other two particles have to add up to zero. So either particle A has spin $1/2$ and particle B has spin$-1/2$, or particle A has spin $-1/2$ and particle B has spin $1/2$.
You obviously don't know which spin particle A is going to have until you measure it. And once you measure it, you automatically know the spin of particle B. Nothing strange about that.
The strange thing is this: Before you measure particle A's spin, the particle itself doesn't know which spin it has. It is in a superposition of spin $1/2$ and spin $-1/2$, and so is particle B. So the whole system is in a superposition of the state (spin$_A$ = 1/2, spin$_B$ = -1/2) and the state (spin$_A$ =-1/2, spin$_B$ = 1/2)
This phenomenon is called entanglement. The point that when you have two entangled particles, you cannot treat them as individual systems.
Let's apply this to a hydrogen atom. For simplicity, we will do this in the framework of quantum mechanics, not quantum field theory.
First, think about the hydrogen atom classically. The electron orbits the nucleus, but the nucleus is not really stationary. The nucleus and the electron both orbit around the system's center of mass. So classically, the position of the nucleus will depend on the position of the electron.
When we quantize the system, this is still true, except we know think of the state of the electron as a superposition of all possible classical states. But each classical state involves the electron being in a certain position and the nucleus being in a certain position. Thus, you have to describe the whole system as a single wavefunction.
And it only becomes localized when we measure it.
Some people claim that when you measure the position of the electron, you also get entangled with the system. Meaning, there is now a version of you which saw the electron at position 1, and another version of you which saw the electron at position 2. This is the core idea behind the many-worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics.

(+1) Could you elaborate on the collapse process, please? Say an electron emits a wave packet in the photon EM field now. Then, several milliseconds later it emits another wave packet. After a while, due to interference, diffraction, etc. the different wave packets are mixed beyond recognition (just as we cannot distinguish one individual wave in the sea), right? Now we perform a measurement, and as you said "it becomes localized when we measure it". But how much of the EM wave field is collapsed, with many waves in EM field entangled already? Surely not the entire EM field of the universe?

+1. Here is more on entanglement and Many Worlds. Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why

@James - Here is more on collapse - Does the collapse of the wave function happen immediately everywhere?

@mmesser314 thank you. Is there an equation that describes many world evolution, like a time dependent Schrodinger equation that captures the full evolution of the many world wavefunction? (I have heard analogies like a "river" splitting, etc. but is there a formal equation for how the "river" splits?)

Entanglement doesn't get you localization. Localization requires an actual irreversible interaction with a piece of matter that we call "the detector" that breaks local Poincare symmetry.

@James What people call "collapse" doesn't exist. A quantum measurement is an irreversible energy transfer of a quantum of energy from the quantum system to a second, completely independent system that we usually call "the measurement device" or "detector". If we want to detect a quantum of energy at position x then we have to introduce an energy absorbing material at position x. The "measurement" is then the physical event that marks the absorption of this energy by the matter of the detector. There is no such thing as measurement without that newly introduced piece of matter.

In the case of pion entanglement made some sense in a way that the properties of one fixes that of the other. But you said electron nucleus and all photons are all entangled. In which sense are they entangled ? Could you elaborate ?

@FlatterMann thanks. Suppose we setup a photon/electron state as consistently as we could 100 times, and perform this measurement (energy exchange between our prepared photon/electron and our prepared detector) 100 times. What causes the outcomes of the interaction to vary so chaotically, and following a specific distribution on top of that (Born's rule)?

@James Relativity. One can't predict the future at the individual event level even in a completely classical relativistic universe. Why? Because causality links the local future to events on the backwards light cone of the future, which at present happens to cover spacelike separated events. For example: information about what happens to one of our Mars rovers RIGHT NOW will only reach us in like ten or twenty minutes due to the radio delay. But when the signal arrives on Earth, its contents are completely unpredictable. In quantum mechanics this is true for all time and spatial scales.

@Ankit I updated the answer to adress your question. As mentioned in the other answers, once you think of the forces being mediated by photons you are no longer doing simple quantum mechanics and have to work in full quantum field theory, which is much more complicated. Thus, I intentionally left out the photon.

An isolated quantum system described by a wavefunction governed by an equation of motion, such as the Schrodinger equation:
$$i\hbar {\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}\Psi (\mathbf{r},t)=\left[-{\frac {\hbar ^{2}}{2m}}\nabla^2+V(\mathbf{r},t)\right]\Psi (\mathbf{r},t)$$
If you drop the time dependence in both the potential and the wavefunction you get a time independent equation. If you solve that equation for the Coulomb potential and the resulting wavefunction can be displayed to look like the clouds you see in many illustrations.
Now if you measure an electron during an interference experiment, then information about the electron spreads to other systems often called the environment, including whatever detector you use to measure the photon, and this produces an effect called decoherence that suppresses the interference:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0105127
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
Decoherence doesn't make quantum systems into particles it just suppresses interference on macroscopic scales for systems that interact heavily with the environment, like the objects you see around you.
How does this fit in with electron clouds? If an atom is interacting relatively weakly with its environment, then the evolution of the atom is dominated by its self Hamiltonian that describes the interaction between the proton and the electron. In these circumstances, decoherence tends to lead to the system being in an energy eigenstate, which doesn't change over time:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9811026
So treating the electron using the strategy outlined at the start of my answer can shed some light on features of real atoms. You can improve the approximation by using relativistic equations and introducing corrections for multiple electrons and so on.

Your question has received many answers, some of which contain part of the information blurred by additional and unnecessary concepts (virtual particles, photons, decoherence, entanglement, perturbation theory, path integrals, quantum field theory, and so on). Therefore, I'll try to use only the necessary concepts.
Particles with mass can be described in the position representation of ordinary Quantum Mechanics (QM) by a wavefunction $\Psi$, i.e., generally, by a complex wavefunction of the space coordinates of the particles and time. The wave function, if normalized, provides a probability density function in the space of particle coordinates through its modulus squared.
The probability density is interpreted as a weight assigned to each small region around some values of the spatial coordinates. From such a weight, we can extract the probability that a measurement of positions performed with high precision on many equally prepared systems will find particles around those values of the coordinates. Ideally, each measurement can be performed with arbitrary precision. This is not entirely correct. There are reasons it is impossible to measure positions with a precision larger than the Compton length of a particle, but for an electron, such a quantity is much smaller than the typical orbital size.
Notice that such a description is the statistical interpretation of the wavefunctions, independent of the particular interpretation scheme of QM.
Particles may have additional degrees of freedom beyond position, such as spin, but we can neglect them for a basic understanding of the electronic clouds around the nucleus found in textbooks.
The electronic clouds correspond to an important approximation of the many-electron wavefunctions, the so-called one-particle approximation. It corresponds to building the many-electron wavefunctions in terms of the solutions of the simplified problem where the electron-electron interaction has been neglected.
Summarizing, one-particle wavefunctions define a probability density for obtaining a value of one electron's position around a space point $\bf r$. In particular, the eigenstates of the problems correspond to stationary states, i.e., states where the probability does not change with time. The meaning of these one-particle wavefunctions implies that if we prepare many systems in the same state (same $\Psi$) and perform many independent experiments to detect the electron position, every time we obtain a point and the set of such points provides a representation of the probability density.
It is important to stress that we deal with independent localization experiments performed on equally prepared systems. The single system, after the electron position measurement will not stay in its original stationary state anymore.
Coming to the original question:

the analogy with the double slit experiment is that it provides a visual illustration of what performing independent measurement of position on an equally prepared set of states means. It also shows that single measurements do not reveal a spatial spreading of the electron properties, but interference patterns result from individual point-like events. In this sense, the naïve duality (quantum particles behave like waves/clouds) has no real support from experiments. The dynamics of a quantum particle have a wave-like character. However, all the measurements on individual particles show well-localized quantities (in no measurement can one observe a fraction of the electronic charge).
The usual cloud-like representation of orbitals in textbooks is a way to provide a visual insight into the region where the probability of finding an electron in a stationary state is higher/smaller. They are based on the probability density (then on $|\Psi|^2$) and represent the outcome of many independent ideal position measurements on equally prepared systems.
The interaction with the nucleus, for hydrogenic wavefunctions, has already been considered by solving exactly the spatial Schrödinger equation. Therefore, we cannot introduce perturbation theory with virtual photons. In a way, the interaction with the nucleus localizes the electron but not over a point-like region. The only meaningful localization is the one described by the stationary wave function, i.e., the typical size of the atomic orbital. Such localization in a stationary state does not prevent the possibility that on a system prepared in such a state, one performs an experiment to determine one electron's position with the maximum precision. We have only to consider that the original stationary state will be lost forever after that measurement.


That the wave function all by itself provides a probability distribution for position is one of the grand mistakes that gets repeated in almost all (if not all) introductory textbooks. First of all that would only be the case for wave functions in spatial representations. The correct answer is that in the spatial representation the operator that we have to stick into the Born rule for the probability of finding a quantum in a position is the unity projection operator. In all other representations it is NOT the trivial unity operator.

The reason why the theory suggests (incorrectly) that we can perform a position measurement at any scale is because this unity operator represents the spectrum of a hypothetical detector made from ultra dense smooth (i.e. non-atomic) matter. It's literally like filling the entire universe with cheese that absorbs all quanta of energy. No such thing can be done in reality below the atomic scale, of course. It is also not necessary. It is much, much better to learn to think of quantum mechanics in momentum space.

@FlatterMann It turns out the orbitals are precisely wave functions in spatial representation.

@FlatterMann Quantum mechanics in momentum space would not be useful for explaining chemistry.

That's a common misconception. A wave function doesn't live in physical space. The wave function of an n-electron system in spatial representation is defined over a 3n dimensional configuration space. Coincidentally 3n=n for n=1 and that is why most people are mistaking configuration space for physical space. They never have to think about the complete problem and the single quantum toy problem is deceptive. Chemists are thinking mostly in terms of momentum space as well. Every time they are talking about binding energies, that's one component of the 4-momentum of the full QM problem.

@FlatterMann You don't have to convince me that the n-electron wavefunction doesn't live in 3D space. However, as I wrote in the answer, there is a useful approximation of one-particle wavefunctions behind the concept of orbitals. One-particle wavefunctions live in 3D space. I leave the last word to chemists about how they think. Those I know better and many renowned solid-state physicists I have met in my professional life prefer to describe the one-particle wavefunctions in the position space.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think the confusion comes from how people talk heuristically about photons. I recommend you reading: What exactly is a photon?.
From the perspective you have in a usual quantum mechanic course, you don't think at all about photons. You rather think about an electron on an electrostatic potential. The axioms of quantum mechanics tell you that the electron gets localised when you try to measure its position, but you can't do that from its interaction with the nucleus.
You could in principle try to have a localised electron trying to measure its position with an external electromagnetic field (heuristically, that's somewhat analogous to what you described as "shooting photons"). Note however that quantum mechanics tell you that a localised electron would not give you a stable atom. The reason why we think of orbitals is that these are stable states (more technically, they are time independent solutions of the Schrödinger equation). If at any time you had a localised electron in an atom, it would probably start moving non-trivially and thus emitting radiation and losing energy (this was actually what motivated Bohr's and Schrödinger's models of the atom). So quantum mechanics tells you that you need non-localised electrons if you want stable atoms.
The concept of "particles exchanging photons" is usually associated with scattering processes in particle physics (i.e. when two free-traveling electrons collide, for example). The equations you need to solve for interaction processes are non-linear and hard (if not impossible) to solve analytically, so you usually solve them by some iterative or perturbative method. It is when you do this (it is called perturbation theory) that in each step/term of the computation, you get some mathematical expression which may be interpreted as particles exchanging photons, i.e. a Feynman diagram.
But as you may see, the concept of "electron exchanging photons" comes from a very different perspective than that of an electron in an electrostatic potential. This picture actually is already present at classical field theory (such as Navier-Stokes for example), see here.

Interaction processes are not non-linear. Quantum mechanics is always linear, even in the case of relativistic quantum field theory and multi-particle systems. The linearity follows from the assumption that quantum mechanical ensembles are statistically independent, i.e. that we can't predict the next event by looking at the results of the last n events. It is of course very hard to "diagonalize" the resulting coupled linear operator equations using free particle (plane wave) solutions. One should not try to interpret Feynman diagrams as actual interactions because it classicizes physics.

@FlatterMann I was refering to non-cuadratic (i.e. interaction) Lagrangian terms, which give non-linear field equations of motion. You are refering to Hamiltonian evolution, which is of course linear.

Even in the case of non-quadratic Lagrangians the actual theory is linear. Individual members of the quantum mechanical ensemble do not interact, even if there are self-interaction terms in the field equations. The linearity of quantum mechanics does not depend on the linearity of the fields. It's a consequence of the ensemble structure of the theory. The real complication in quantum field theory doesn't even arise from the coupling terms. It's the different infinities, some of which are of mathematical origin. The hard ones are the physical ones.
